# Why might data disappear from internal storage?

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist, hashmap

In my application, I save large, serialized `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`s

There are between six and twelve strings in each hashmap. In testing, I save arrays of length two hundred at most.

An issue has arisen whereby this data goes missing in the live environment. There are no crashes reported, and I'm unable to repeat the problem myself with test data. When users attempt to view a list comprised of some of this data, it appears empty. The list is definitely saved on the phone and successfully loaded at least once, but after this does not load successfully. As far as I am aware, this only happens when a user has a large amount of data stored in this way.

Are there any limits to data size, or other knows issues, that could possibly be causing this?
As I said, I find it impossible to replicate so it seems to be an issue with large arraylists or with different phone types.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, try to save them in parts and join them together (if needed)? Or try to save them in a binary form and compress them on-the-fly? I know it's not an answer, thus just made a comment. Ps.: How large is large? Android runs on toasters, not just top-notch devices. Take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if a user is using a older device. If the application uses more than what the device can allocate it then the deice will try to free up space to keep the app running. The best thing you can do is to try to limit the size of your Array to keep memory usage low.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way I could be storing my data? For example, if I define an array that holds data from my hashmaps in a particular known location, would this be smaller on the device?

Comment: Well there are many ways of doing this. But it depends on what you mean by storing... If its like save data then you can look into serialization and input/output streams. If its temporary then you can look into caching.

Comment: Well, it's serializing using an output stream that I'm doing. I wondered if I could get it to take up a smaller space on the phone if I saved it another way. Is there a way to get the program to send me a log if there isn't enough room on the phone?

Comment: Well in a try/Catch you can get IOException. But why are you doing a arraylist of a hashmap??? Cant you just ArrayList<List<String,String>>

Comment: Or even just List<String, String> or String[][]

Comment: It was honestly just a decision made when I was relatively new to java programming. Each hashmap represents on item with several attributes of which there are several in each list. Just seemed intuitive when I did it; I could store all the data and easily get the value of a required attribute by entering the key. What are the advantages of using a List<String, String> over a hashmap?

Comment: **List:**

`An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of     this interface has precise control over where in the list each     element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer     index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.`
    
**HashMap:**

`An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.`

Comment: Yeah I appreciate that. I actually didn't want to have duplicate keys. I just thought there may be a good reason that I shouldn't be using a hashmap. To give you some context, each HashMap represents a cow (I'm not kidding) and each List<HashMap> represents a herd. Sometimes I don't have all the details on a cow; sometimes they need to be overridden and most of the time I need to be able to get certain information about a cow. Just thought HashMaps made sense for that.

Comment: Then maby you can do. Hashmap<String, List<cows>>

Comment: As in the cow is just a string or a class called cow?

Comment: No cow is just a string Hashmap<String, List<String>>